# How Secure Is Azure's FTP Deployment?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app set up with Microsoft Azure. Right now, I'm using FTP to copy files to the server.

My question is, given that the FTP password is a very short randomly generated string (that I don't seem to be able to change) and the username is literally the name of my website, how secure is this method of deployment?

Would it be possible for someone to brute force the password and wreck havoc on my server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question, and there's simply no way to post a valid answer to this.

Comment: Seriously: If you have an issue with ftp, don't use it. There are numerous source control providers built in to Web Apps. Also note: Web Apps provides `ftps`, obviating the need for `ftp` - just look at your "essentials" settings and you'll see the `ftps` url.

Answer (score 1):

You can use user or site credentials to access FTP, as explained [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials).

But your statement "*the FTP password is a very short randomly generated string*" is incorrect.

- If you use user credentials, you choose the password and it can be anything you want,
- If you use site credentials, the generated password is extremely long, and looks like `TbxwnfdldajYrmNyKNB2Amz8cqxaK19mihKMNtY3dxMPgxK8xl2HLxRkZpDt`

Also, you should use FTPS instead of FTP. Both are supported and FTPS is more secure.

Bottom line, there shouldn't be any issue here.